# How to make vim quick fix window on the right side?

Tags: vim, position

If I "`:copen`" it's by default at the bottom.

If I "`:botright copen`" it's still at the bottom.

How to make it on the right side of my source file window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **move** any window to the right side you can press  <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

Otherwise, you can use `vertical` :

```
:vertical copen
```

---

Comment: It's `<C-w>L`, not `L`.